# Live data stripchart plotting in browser using comet

Tags: javascript, html, charts, plot, comet

I would like to plot several curves of data in a shared chart, browser side, with the data pushed from the server using one of the more recent comet-style long-running connections preferably failing back to polling where not supported.

Prefer open source, specifically so I can add some customizations that I know will be needed. 
HTML5 Canvas etc is ok as well, failing back to other/older technology would be nice but not required.

I know Flot is popular for this, but I didn't see that it supported COMET styl streaming, unless I overlooked this.

I know I found a pretty nice project matching these requirements a while back, but just can't find it now. Woops ;)